# How to parse a javascript list containing dictionary in python django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a webhook.

```
data0=[{"senderId":"smsdia","requestId":"******383233353233","report":[{"date":"2017-12-02 17:00:41","number":"12345","status":"1","desc":"DELIVERED"}],"userId":"119385","campaignName":"viaSOCKET"}]
```

I receive the above data in a POST request to my server.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

How do I parse it?

I know that if it is a list:  `data1=['sree','kanth']` I can parse it with `request.POST.getlist('data1[]')`

But I don't know how to parse when it is a list containing dict.

**edit1**

Moreover, I get `len(data1) is 2`. But `len(data0) is 0.`

**edit2**
using request.lib:
https://requestb.in/13df2891?inspect

Comment: You need to provide more information. This is probably JSON, but it's not at all clear how it is being sent. Please show the code that is posting to your server.

Comment: I don't have control over the code that is posting to my server.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please see the posted data at https://requestb.in/13df2891?inspect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be JSON sent inside a form field. You can use the `json` library to parse it:

```
data = json.loads(request.POST['data'])
```